# Can I use syntax to rename categorical X-axis graph labels in SPSS?

Tags: syntax, spss

In SPSS, using syntax I have drawn a line graph where the x-axis represents 9 different categories. [Example of the plot I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXe2J.png)

I have two questions:

1. How do I rename the x-axis labels using syntax? Instead of having the variable names in each of the categories(eg: Auto_SDYaw_Sec1_E2), I wish to rename them to "Sec 1", "Sec 2", etc.
2. How do I plot a vertical line between the 2nd and 3rd variable/x-axis category?

I can draw a vertical line ON the variable by using this code:

```
GUIDE: form.line(position("2"), color(color.black))
```

However, changing 'position' to 2.5 doesn't work.

My whole code is as follows:

```
* Chart Builder.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=MEANSE(Auto_SDYaw_Sec1_E2, 2) MEANSE(Auto_SDYaw_Sec2_E2, 2) MEANSE(Auto_SDYaw_Sec3_E2, 2) MEANSE(Auto_SDYaw_Sec4_E2, 2) MEANSE(Auto_SDYaw_Sec5_E2, 2) MEANSE(Auto_SDYaw_Sec6_E2, 2) MEANSE(Auto_SDYaw_Sec7_E2, 2) MEANSE(Auto_SDYaw_Sec8_E2, 2) MEANSE(Auto_SDYaw_Sec9_E2, 2) LaneChange_Auto_2 MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
    TRANSFORM=VARSTOCASES(SUMMARY="#SUMMARY" INDEX="#INDEX" LOW="#LOW" HIGH="#HIGH")
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: SUMMARY=col(source(s), name("#SUMMARY"))
  DATA: INDEX=col(source(s), name("#INDEX"), unit.category())
  DATA: LaneChange_Auto_2=col(source(s), name("LaneChange_Auto_2"), unit.category())
  DATA: LOW=col(source(s), name("#LOW"))
  DATA: HIGH=col(source(s), name("#HIGH"))
  GUIDE: form.line(position("2"), color(color.black))
  GUIDE: text.title( label( "Light Fog" ) )
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Mean"))
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), label("Critical Event 1: Automated Condition"))
  GUIDE: text.footnote(label("Error Bars: +/- 2 SE"))
  SCALE: cat(dim(1), include("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0), max(20))
  SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), include("0", "1"))
  ELEMENT: line(position(INDEX*SUMMARY), color.interior(LaneChange_Auto_2), missing.wings())
  ELEMENT: interval(position(region.spread.range(INDEX*(LOW+HIGH))), shape.interior(shape.ibeam), color.interior(LaneChange_Auto_2))
END GPL.
```

Thank you!